# Blueimp-gallery with folder structure (Razor template)

Tags: blueimp, 2sxc

I have a scenario where a customer need an image gallery with a folder-structure.
They want to use it as a product-reference for customers.

I am looking at the blueimp-gallery APP, and it looks like a good "starter template". I have created a folder-structure with the Library input-type (Adam upload), but is there a way to list the Adam folder-structure in the view template (Razor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but almost :)

So first of all, there is a new version of the Blueimp which actually supports multi-album out of the box. We've been using it for a while, but are finishing some details before we publish it this or next week.

Many people ask "can I connect my folder xyz to ADAM" but that's trying to solve the problem backwards, assuming that the folder is the best place to put things, and now adam should talk to it. ADAM works the other way around, since it should fully manage the resources - which it can't when using a folder where the user will probably "mess around" manually.

So to continue on the answer: ADAM support subfolders :) you can even specify the depth.

So to continue, I recommend that you either
1. get the latest blueimp release from github - or even better, wait another 2 weeks and use that...
2. or in your current blueimp, enable subfolders in the ADAM, then modify the output-script to respect that in any way you wish

Good luck!